# Creating a template with an operation and a data type c++

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

In my project, similar code is used in two places. I would like to create a template to avoid this repetition of code.
Here's the first case:

```
IAsyncOperation<GattCharacteristicsResult> charListResult = service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
while (charListResult.Status() != AsyncStatus::Completed) {
    continue;
}
GattCharacteristicsResult charListR = charListResult.GetResults();
```

And here is the second case:

```
IAsyncOperation<GattDescriptorsResult> discrOper = characteristic.GetDescriptorsAsync();
while (discrOper.Status() != AsyncStatus::Completed) {
    continue;
}
GattDescriptorsResult descrR = discrOper.GetResults();
```

The most that I could achieve is:

```
template<class Operation>
GattCharacteristicsResult getNested1(Operation operation) {
    IAsyncOperation<GattCharacteristicsResult> result = operation();
    while (result.Status() != AsyncStatus::Completed) {
        continue;
    }
    return result.GetResults();
}
```

And, accordingly, using the template:

```
attCharacteristicsResult charListR = getNested1([&service]() { return service.GetCharacteristicsAsync(); });
```

But this is not enough. I need to get rid of 'GattCharacteristicsResult'. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't `IAsyncOperation` have a `Wait` function or similar. The active waiting bothers me.

Comment: Sure, active waiting is not nice. But main thread can not waiting (at last I get an error while tryed co_await). So, for that example I did that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can also template the return type and then explicitly specify it in the call:

```
template<class ResultType, class Operation>
ResultType getNested1(Operation operation) {
    IAsyncOperation<ResultType> result = operation();
    while (result.Status() != AsyncStatus::Completed) {
        continue;
    }
    return result.GetResults();
}
```

and

```
auto charListR = getNested1<GattCharacteristicsResult>(...);
```

Or just use auto and let the compiler deduce the necessary types:

```
template<class Operation>
decltype(auto) getNested1(Operation operation) {
    auto result = operation();
    while (result.Status() != AsyncStatus::Completed) {
        continue;
    }
    return result.GetResults();
}
```

I don't have a compiler at hand right now so I'm not sure if the above works, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Many thanks. You have a small typo in the first example: template<class ResultType, class Operation> if you can, correct it, suddenly it will come in handy for someone. Thanks again!